# Passport-JWT throwing secretOrKey Provider error

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I am using Passport-JWT strategy for authentication but i am getting an error when we have to provide secret. This is I have so far

```
const jwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy();
const ExtractJwt=require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User =require('../models/user');
const config=require('../config/database')

module.exports=function(passport)
{
let opts={}
opts.jwtFromRequest=ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
opts.secretOrKey=config.secret; 

passport.use(new jwtStrategy(opts,(jwt_payload,done)=>{
    User.getUserById(jwt_payload._id,(err,user)=>{
        if(err) 
        {
            return done(err,false);
        }
        if(user)
        {
            return done(null,user);
        }
        else
        {
            return done(null,false);
        }

    });
}));}
```

I am getting this error

> C:\dev\mapd713\HealthCare Project\node_modules\passport-jwt\lib\strategy.js:33
>       this._secretOrKeyProvider = options.secretOrKeyProvider;
>                                           ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'secretOrKeyProvider' of undefined
>       at Object.JwtStrategy [as Strategy] (C:\dev\mapd713\HealthCare Project\node_modules\passport-jwt\lib\strategy.js:33:41)
>       at Object. (C:\dev\mapd713\HealthCare Project\config\passport.js:1:107)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (C:\dev\mapd713\HealthCare Project\server.js:35:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)

I Followed this question [I'm getting an error authenticating with Password-JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49440973/im-getting-an-error-authenticating-with-password-jwt) but still not able to solve the issue. I'm using version '^4.0.0' of passport-jwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Figured it out as the main problem was with my **require** statement as I was importing **Strategy** as a Method but I think from 2.x version they updated it as i'm using 4.x version

```
const jwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy; //<--- REMOVE ()
const ExtractJwt=require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User =require('../models/user');
const config=require('../config/database')
module.exports=function(passport)
{
let opts={}
opts.jwtFromRequest=ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey=config.secret;

passport.use(new jwtStrategy(opts,(jwt_payload,done)=>{

    User.getUserById(jwt_payload._id,(err,user)=>{
        if(err) 
        {
            return done(err,false);
        }
        if(user)
        {
            return done(null,user);
        }
        else
        {
            return done(null,false);
        }

    });
}));
}
```

Hope this Help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your key is `undefined`. Please try that with function as express middleware, something like this

```
function dummyMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', config.secret, function(err, jwtPayload) {
        if (err || !jwtPayload) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        }
        req.jwtPayload = jwtPayload;
        next();
    }) (req, res, next)
}
```

Then use it like

```
app.use('/your_secure_path', dummyMiddleware);
```